# Python Synthax Error: Invalid Syntax with Elifs

Tags: python-3.x

I Am Working On a Calculator for a School Final Project. I Am Very New To Python and Do Not Know Why My Elifs have SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I would also appreciate some help on printing floats with 2 decimal points since I am very unsure about how to go with that. Thanks!

```
# This is a calculator that calculates Addition, Subtraction, Division, Multiplication and Powers. 
# It must round all answers to atleast 2 decimal points.

print ("Welcome! Choose what Type of operation you would like, 1: Addition, 2: Subtraction, 3: Multiplication, 4: Division, 5: Powers.")
Choice = int(input("Your Choice ( 1 - 5 ): "))

if Choice <= 0 or Choice > 5:
    print ("Invalid Entry")

elif Choice == 1 or Choice == 2 or Choice == 3 or Choice == 4 or Choice == 5:
    num1 = float(input("Your First Number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Your Second Number: "))


if Choice == 1:
    Addition = num1 + num2
    print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Addition, 2))

elif Choice == 2:
    Subtraction = num1 - num2
    print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Subtraction, 2))

elif Choice == 3:
    Multiplication = num1 * num2
    print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Multiplication, 2))

elif Choice == 4:
    Division = num1 / num2
    print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Division, 2))

elif Choice == 5:
    Powers =num1 / num2
    print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Powers, 2))

else:
    print ("Invalid Entry")
```

Comment: your print statements are missing a `)` at the end. you have 3 `(` and only 2 `)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your print statments. In these you open your print with `(` then you open str with `(` then open round with `(` then you close round with `)` and close str with `)` but you dont close your print statement with `)`. So you have 3 `(` but only 2 `)` So you need to add `)` to the end of you print lines to close the statement.

However if you find your self repeating your code alot like you print statments then there is probably a better way to do it. Below is just an example of how you can write this in a cleaner way

```py
# This is a calculator that calculates Addition, Subtraction, Division, Multiplication and Powers.
# It must round all answers to atleast 2 decimal points.

print("Welcome! Choose what Type of operation you would like, 1: Addition, 2: Subtraction, 3: Multiplication, 4: Division, 5: Powers.")
Choice = int(input("Your Choice ( 1 - 5 ): "))

if 1 <= Choice <= 5:
    num1 = float(input("Your First Number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Your Second Number: "))
    result = 0
    if Choice == 1:
        result = num1 + num2
    elif Choice == 2:
        result = num1 - num2
    elif Choice == 3:
        result = num1 * num2
    elif Choice == 4:
        result = num1 / num2
    elif Choice == 5:
        result = num1 ** num2
    print("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(result, 2)))
else:
    print("Invalid Entry")
```

Comment: Thanks So Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

> Observed that indentation and print statement brackets are not closed. Here is the corrected version for reference:

```
# This is a calculator that calculates Addition, Subtraction, Division, Multiplication and Powers. 
# It must round all answers to atleast 2 decimal points.

print ("Welcome! Choose what Type of operation you would like, 1: Addition, 2: Subtraction, 3: Multiplication, 4: Division, 5: Powers.")
Choice = int(input("Your Choice ( 1 - 5 ): "))

if Choice <= 0 or Choice > 5:
    print ("Invalid Entry")

elif Choice == 1 or Choice == 2 or Choice == 3 or Choice == 4 or Choice == 5:
    num1 = float(input("Your First Number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Your Second Number: "))
    if Choice == 1:
        Addition = num1 + num2
        print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Addition, 2)))

    elif Choice == 2:
        Subtraction = num1 - num2
        print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Subtraction, 2)))

    elif Choice == 3:
        Multiplication = num1 * num2
        print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Multiplication, 2)))

    elif Choice == 4:
        Division = num1 / num2
        print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Division, 2)))

    elif Choice == 5:
        Powers =num1 / num2
        print ("Your Final Number Is: " + str(round(Powers, 2)))

    else:
        print ("Invalid Entry")
```